# Why are there events missing in famous-angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

I have been trying to get into using it to develop a desktop browser application.However, I noticed that when using the library and examining the API that basically no events were included for use on desktop machines. That is, no event bindings for mouse events.

This lead me to two conclusions, first that famous-angular is meant primarily for mobile phones or that the libraries are so new that they have not had a moment to implement them. I can tell by looking at the events available in famous itself, that desktop browsers are supported.

Have I just misunderstood the direction taken by the library developers and I am using the wrong tools for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get hold of Steve Newcomb who gave me the following response:

`The first release has the atomic physics engine necessary to build responsive design, but you need to custom role your app from there.  When we release our app templates and widgets in August, they will have responsiveness built in.`

This indicates that the libraries themselves are so new and are still under a lot of development at the moment and most likely the responsive aspects as well as desktop interactions will be arriving soon.

The libraries were developed with a "mobile first" mindset so this is not really surprising now that I look back on it.